# Ease process for gathering metadata from PDF, DJVU, EBOOK files

Tags: bash

Learning Bash using hunt and peck method. Following code was put together from results of many "How do I ..." searches. Thus styling may be inconsistent. See code for my motivation. Any advice gratefully accepted.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Motivation:
#   To ease the process of examining large quantities
#   of files for metadata and writing gathered metadata
#   to a file in a separate directory using examined file's
#   name with a .txt extension.
#
#   Saves opening a file manager, text editor, and document
#   viewer, and then closing same for each file processed. 

# Usage:
#   cd to a directory filled with a large number of 
#   PDF, DJVU, EBOOK etc. files. Invoke getmetadata
#   with no arguments. getmetadata will create a META
#   directory with two files; FILELIST and NEXTFILE.
#
#   FILELIST contains a list of files in the CWD. NEXTFILE
#   contains a bookmark to the next file to process.
#
#   Upon invoking getmetadata, will open the current file
#   in the Atril Document Viewer, prompt user for metadata,
#   save the gathered metadata to a similarly named file in the
#   META directory, store a bookmark to the next file to process.
#
#   Press CTRL-C to close instance of Atril and exit getmetadata.
#   The next invocation will resume at the bookmarked file.
#   getmetadata will print "Finished" to the terminal when last
#   file in list has been processed.

trap "exit" INT TERM ERR
trap "kill 0" EXIT

# Setup directory structure, or not if already setup.
function check_filesystem {
    
    # no files to process in directory.
    if [ -z "$(ls -A "$PWD")" ]
    then
        echo "Empty directory... exiting"
        exit 0
    fi
    
    # if META is missing or empty:
    if [ ! -d ./META ]
    then
        echo >&2 "Creating ... ./META"
        mkdir ./META
    fi
    
    # if FILELIST is missing or empty;
    if [ ! -s ./META/FILELIST ]
    then
        echo >&2 "Creating ... ./META/FILELIST";        
        find "$PWD" -type f | sort > ./META/FILELIST
        echo >&2 "Creating ... ./META/NEXTFILE";
        read -r firstline < ./META/FILELIST
        printf '%s\n' "$firstline" > ./META/NEXTFILE
    fi
    
    # if NEXTFILE list is missing or empty;
    if [ ! -s ./META/NEXTFILE ]
    then
        echo >&2 "Creating ... ./META/NEXTFILE";
        read -r firstline < ./META/FILELIST
        printf '%s\n' "$firstline" > ./META/NEXTFILE
    fi
        
}

# Updates bookmark.
function update_bookmark {
    
    # get the next file to operate upon
    # from the NEXTFILE bookmark file
    # call it the CURRENT file
    read -r CURRENT < ./META/NEXTFILE
    
    # find the NEXT file to operate upon
    # after we finish processing the CURRENT file
    # save it to NEXTFILE

    # if the FILELIST exactly matches the present contents of
    # the CWD and META is the only directory then line contains
    # an extra element in the path. Likely not a good test.
    # Anyway a crappy way to break out of a loop.
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        if [ "$line" == "$CURRENT" ]
        then
            s1="$(dirname "$(head -n 1 ./META/FILELIST)")"
            s2="$(dirname "$line")"
            if [ "$s1" != "$s2" ]
            then
                echo "Finished"
                exit 0
            fi
            read -r NEXT
            printf '%s\n' "$NEXT" > ./META/NEXTFILE         
        fi
    done < ./META/FILELIST
}

# Processes current file.
function process_current {
    # open the CURRENT file in Atril
    if [ -z "$CURRENT" ]
    then
        echo "No Files"
        exit 0
    fi
    atril "$CURRENT" &
    
    # get current metadata values from file
    TITLE=$(exiftool -s3 -Title "$CURRENT")
    AUTHOR=$(exiftool -s3 -Author "$CURRENT")
    SUBJECT=$(exiftool -s3 -Subject "$CURRENT")
    KEYWORDS=$(exiftool -s3 -Keywords "$CURRENT")
    
    # ask user for new metadata values
    # entering a blank value will keep existing value
    read -e -p -r "Title [$TITLE]: " NEW_TITLE
    read -e -p -r "Author [$AUTHOR]: " NEW_AUTHOR
    read -e -p -r "Subject [$SUBJECT]: " NEW_SUBJECT
    read -e -p -r "Keywords [$KEYWORDS]: " NEW_KEYWORDS
    
    # set to existing values if we got a blank entry
    NEW_TITLE="${NEW_TITLE:-${TITLE}}"
    NEW_AUTHOR="${NEW_AUTHOR:-${AUTHOR}}"
    NEW_SUBJECT="${NEW_SUBJECT:-${SUBJECT}}"
    NEW_KEYWORDS="${NEW_KEYWORDS:-${KEYWORDS}}"
    
    FILENAME=$(basename "$CURRENT")
    
    # write metadata to file named 
    # basename CURRENT + .txt to the
    # META directory
    printf "%s\n" \
            "${NEW_TITLE}" \
            "${NEW_AUTHOR}" \
            "${NEW_SUBJECT}" \
            "${NEW_KEYWORDS}" \
    > ./META/"${FILENAME%%.*}"".txt"
}

check_filesystem
update_bookmark
process_current

# Ctrl-C will close Atril instance and exit this script
wait
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> trap "exit" INT TERM ERR
> ```

The normal response to `INT` and `TERM` is to exit with a failure value, rather than a success value.  I'd leave that alone, and additionally make `ERR` do the same with a simple `set -e`.  Also a good idea to `set -u` to help us detect use of unset variables.

> ```
> if [ -z "$(ls -A "$PWD")" ]
> ```

My first response is "Don't parse `ls` ouptut!" - but this seems fine.  The alternative (glob to an array variable, with `shopt -o nullglob` set, and then test its length) is much longer, and would be worth encapsulating into a function.  Though we could consider testing to see if we can find any *regular* files: `if $(find . -type f -printf false -quit); then echo "Empty directory... exiting"; exit 0; fi`.

---

> ```
> if [ ! -d ./META ]
> ```

Would be simpler without the explicit mention of `./`:

```
if [ ! -d META ]
```

---

> ```
>         find "$PWD" -type f | sort > ./META/FILELIST
> ```

Perhaps we should exclude `META` from the list:

```
        find "$PWD" -name META -prune -o -type f -print | sort > META/FILELIST
```

There's a weakness here if users create filenames containing newlines.  The GNU tools provide options for using null character to separate filenames instead of newline:

```
find … -print0 | sort -z
```

We can read such a file in Bash using `read -d ''`.

---

> ```
>     read -r firstline < ./META/FILELIST
>     printf '%s\n' "$firstline" > ./META/NEXTFILE
> ```

That looks like `head -n 1 <META/FILELIST >META/NEXTFILE`.  (Add `-z` flag for NUL-separated values).

---

> ```
>     read -r CURRENT < ./META/NEXTFILE
> ```

Prefer to use lower-case for shell variables, as this helps distinguish them from environment variables such as `LANG` that are used to communicate preferences to programs.

---

> ```
> while IFS= read -r line; do
>     ⋮
>     s1="$(dirname "$(head -n 1 ./META/FILELIST)")"
>     ⋮
> done < ./META/FILELIST
> ```

Shellcheck picked up on this as a confusing business reading the same file twice in this loop.  We shouldn't be changing its contents, so it's probably best to hoist the initialisation of `s1` out of the loop (and give it a better name!).

---

> ```
> read -e -p -r "Title [$TITLE]: " NEW_TITLE
> read -e -p -r "Author [$AUTHOR]: " NEW_AUTHOR
> read -e -p -r "Subject [$SUBJECT]: " NEW_SUBJECT
> read -e -p -r "Keywords [$KEYWORDS]: " NEW_KEYWORDS
> ```

Prompting with `-r` looks wrong.  I think you meant `-p "Title [$TITLE]: "` etc.  Instead of including a default in the prompt, consider using `-i "$TITLE"` to make it the initial contents of the edit buffer - that's useful when the user needs to make only small changes to the inferred title:

```
read -e -p "Title: " -i "$TITLE" TITLE
```

---

> ```
> NEW_TITLE="${NEW_TITLE:-${TITLE}}"
> NEW_AUTHOR="${NEW_AUTHOR:-${AUTHOR}}"
> NEW_SUBJECT="${NEW_SUBJECT:-${SUBJECT}}"
> NEW_KEYWORDS="${NEW_KEYWORDS:-${KEYWORDS}}"
> ```

Since we use these only once from here, we could just inline those where needed:

```
printf "%s\n" \
        "${NEW_TITLE:-$TITLE}" \
        "${NEW_AUTHOR:-$AUTHOR}" \
        "${NEW_SUBJECT:-$SUBJECT}" \
        "${NEW_KEYWORDS:-$KEYWORDS}" \
```

Though if you follow the suggestion to use `read -i` we no longer need the `NEW_*` variables at all.

Comment: thanks much for your comments. I have edited my original post to include a revised version. Additional comments gladly accepted.